# Return page to original scrollTop position after closing popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I have a button which fixes the position of the page content then pushes it left while a form slides in from the right.

This is working fine except for one thing. When the user has scrolled down the page slightly and clicks on the button it successfully fixes the position. However when they then close this form, the page does not return to the original position... it takes the user back to the top of the page. I've posted the jquery below which might help to explain the problem better.

There's also a jsfiddle example here...

http://jsfiddle.net/CMbBC/

```
    var pageContents;
    var currentscrollpos;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a#testbutton").live('click', function() {
            var currentscrollpos = $(window).scrollTop();
            var pageContents = $("body").html();
            $("body").html("");
            $("<div class='pageContainer'>" + pageContents + "</div>").prependTo("body");
            $(".pageContainer").css({'position':'fixed','top':currentscrollpos*-1});
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
            $("<div class='blackout'></div>").appendTo("body");
            $(".blackout").css("opacity",0.8).fadeIn('slow', function() {
                $("<div class='popupPanel'><a class='closeme'>close</a></div>").appendTo("body");
                $(".popupPanel").animate({
                    right: "0px"
                }, 500, function() {
                    $(".popupPanel").css("position","absolute")
                });
                $(".pageContainer").animate({
                    left: "-200px"
                }, 500, function() {
                });
                $("a#testbutton").append(currentscrollpos)
            });
            return false;
        });

        $('.closeme').live('click', function() {
            var pageContents = $(".pageContainer").html();
            $(".popupPanel").css("position","fixed").animate({
                right: "-200px"
            }, 500, function() {

            });
            $(".pageContainer").animate({
                left: "0px"
            }, 500, function() {
                $(".blackout").fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    $(".blackout").remove();
                    $("body").html(pageContents);   
                    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: currentscrollpos }, 0);
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a *local* variable because you are using `var`:

```
var currentscrollpos = $(window).scrollTop();
```

Instead, drop the `var` so that it's accessible inside the `.closeme` click function. You already used `var` at the very beginning. So:

```
currentscrollpos = $(window).scrollTop();
```

That way, the variable at the very beginning will be set, which can be accessed by both functions. Currently, you are declaring another variable inside the `a#testbutton` click function, leaving the original variable untouched.

http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/CMbBC/2/.

Comment: if $(window) doesn't work you can try with $(document.body) or $("body")

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to return to the position of the page that is closed from the browser

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var currentposition;
    $(document).ready(function(){                    
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
            console.log("scrollPos:"+scrollPos);
                            
            localStorage.setItem("key",scrollPos);                            
        });
        currentposition=localStorage.getItem("key");
                                                   
        window.scrollTo(0,currentposition);
        alert("currentposition:"+currentposition);                    
    });
</script>
```